# All files made by root is write-protected

Tags: linux, file, permissions, directory, root

Is it normal that all files and folders, which is made by root, is write-protected?
For instance, take a look at terminal log below:

```
shine@Shine-Ubuntu:~$ sudo -s
root@Shine-Ubuntu:~# echo >> 1.txt
root@Shine-Ubuntu:~# exit
exit
shine@Shine-Ubuntu:~$ rm 1.txt
rm: remove write-protected regular file '1.txt'?
```

(As you might know, `echo >> FILE_NAME` creates a file and names it `FILE_NAME`.)

When a file is made by root, and i want to delete it via user, it says `remove write-protected regular file 'FILE_NAME'?`

What should i do so the files and folders made by root won't be write-protected?

Comment: **UMASK** is the default permissions given when a new file or folder is created on a Linux machine. Detailed documentation/usage of umask can be seen [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uumask.htm). Check umask setting on your system.

Comment: Thanks. Solved. I used `umask 000` and the files and folders made by root is not write-protected.

Comment: you should not use umask 000 as this gives other users write permission as well. Use umask 022 which gives read+write permission to root user and only read permission to group, other users. Also I posted my response as answer to this question, please mark the response as accepted answer (only if this solved your problem :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UMASK** is the default permissions given when a new file or folder is created on a Linux machine. Detailed documentation/usage of umask can be seen [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uumask.htm). Check umask setting on your system